# How to ensure that image is selected or not using angular file upload

Tags: html, angular-file-upload

I am using angular File upload But the problem is , required attribute of file upload is not ensuring that image available or not.

```
 <input type="file" name="picture" class="ion ion-camera" required nv-file-select uploader="uploader">
```

How can I ensure that image is selected\uploaded so that I am enable register button. Which need to be disabled if user didn't add photo.

Comment: Do you mean how to ensure that the selected file was image (jpeg/png/gif/ and so on)?

Comment: yes also that a file is selected